# Ubuntu does not update date and time

Tags: time, lxc, date

I click on the clock in the upper bar and I choose the Time and Date Settings, manually do not let me put another time different from the one that is configured in the BIOS, if I select the automatic option does not update the time.

[image]
[image]

The system is running inside a Linux-Station virtual machine, a type of LXC setup.

Comment: @DavidFoerster Hi,does not respond to instructions, any idea of ​​what may be happening?

Comment: @DavidFoerster manually the entered times don't persist and when I select automatic the time is not updated.

Comment: What happens when you try to set the time via the `date` tool, i. e. run `date -s <DATE>` to set the date and time and run `date` again without arguments to check the result? See the section “Date String” of the [`date(1)` manual](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/date.1.html) for a description of the format of `<DATE>`. Something like `4 hours 37 minutes ago` should work too if you want to set the new time relative to the current system time.

Comment: @DavidFoerster Date: can not set date: Operation not allowed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51766/discussion-between-david-foerster-and-alberto).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

During our chat it became clear that the system in question is actually a “Linux Container” ([LXC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LXC)). This type of [operating-system-level virtualization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating-system-level_virtualization) usually doesn't allow changes to the host system. In particular, the guest system can't change the configuration of the kernel that it shares with the host system. This includes kernel services like the system time.

See also:

- [date: cannot set date: Operation not permitted](//serverfault.com/q/508922)
- [[lxc-users] "date: cannot set date: Operation not permitted" inside Lxc Container](https://lists.linuxcontainers.org/pipermail/lxc-users/2015-April/008906.html)